# Show specific posts as static html/php

Tags: customization

I need to show a few paginated posts as static html/php. BTW, i don't care about SEO (please please please don't lecture me that i should).

Found 2 plugins:

1)Really Static. Doesn't work with paginated posts and somehow traffic starts flowing to generated messed up pages.

2)WP Static HTML Output. Needs to have permalinks updated, which i can't really do for various reasons.

Does anyone have any other ideas or know any other plugins to make it happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WP Super Cache plugin and set it to make static html for any page on your WordPress website. It can be fully customized on which pages to be served as static html and which pages not.